# Trigger anchor click on div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div elements and if a div is clicked, I want to trigger a click event on the inner`<a></a>` tag. I need to do this, as there are validation functions on the click function of the anchor tags and they are not rendered by me.

This is my approach to do it:

```js
$('.wrapperDiv').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.link').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapperDiv">
      <a class="link" href="https://google.com/" target="_self">Test A</a>
    </div>

  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapperDiv">
      <a class="link" href="https://bing.com/" target="_blank">Test B</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Why do I get Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded and how can I fix this?

[image: maximum call stack size exceeded]

Comment: btw, it's anchor, anker is a german word only. ;-)

Comment: You are getting this error cause the click that you programmatically trigger on the anchor element, is also picked up by the div element (that's how click events work). Can you call the validation function in another way than by clicking the element?

Comment: @cloned not only German, it's also a Dutch word :)

Comment: You learn something new every day. Thanks @thomaux

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `e.preventDefault();` after `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation()` only prevent to trigger parent element click, Just do it with div click:

```js
$('.wrapperDiv').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var link = $(e.currentTarget).find('.link')
    var win = window.open(link.attr('href'), link.attr('target'));
    win.focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapperDiv">
      <a class="link" href="https://google.com/" target="_self">Test A</a>
    </div>

  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapperDiv">
      <a class="link" href="https://bing.com/" target="_blank">Test B</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```